# Estimate characters in a single line of TextView using monospace font

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to estimate the number of characters I can place on a single line in a `TextView`. The idea is to get the display width, and then divide it by the width of a character. (I'm using display width because it appears all the methods to get the view width are broken).

Here is the `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblNumbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

And during `onCreate`:

```
final TextView lblNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNumbers);
if (lblNumbers != null) {
    lblNumbers.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
}
```

I hope the monospace font should make this easy (or easier).

I can retrieve the `Typeface`, but I can't seem to find any methods to get the text metrics:

```
final TextView lblNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNumbers);
if (lblNumbers != null) {
    Typeface tf = lblNumbers.getTypeface();
}
```

How does one determine the width of a character used in the `TextView` with the `monospace` font?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the definitive way, but you could use the `measureText()` method of the TextPaint returned from `TextView#getPaint()`.

Answer (score 0):

Mike was right - the information was available in the [`TextPaint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html) object.

```
Float pixelWidth = 1.0f;
DisplayMetrics dm = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
if (dm != null) {
    pixelWidth = (float) dm.widthPixels;
    Log.d("PRNG", "Display width: " + pixelWidth.toString());
}

Float charWidth = 1.0f;
TextView lblNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNumbers);
if (lblNumbers != null) {
    charWidth = lblNumbers.getPaint().measureText(" ");
    Log.d("PRNG", "Text width: " + charWidth.toString());
}

/* The extra gyrations negate Math.round's rounding up */
int charPerLine = Math.round(pixelWidth - 0.5f) / Math.round(charWidth - 0.5f);
```